# Satellite link: can intermediate 8000 km height satellites provide connection in aircrafts

Tags: routing

O3b Networks provides a 8063 km height satellite network over the equator. This allows to provide an internet connection with 4x lower latency than when using geostationary satellite links. The connection is provided to fixed points on earth, as well as to ships over the oceans.

For ships, they use a beam tracking system (as of the provider datasheet):

> - O3b’s satellite beams follow the ship on its normal route.
> - O3b maintains the ship within the beam centre.
> - O3b receives latitude/longitude updates on two hour intervals via in-band or out-of-band channel.
> - Beam tracking updates in real time if the ship has to change course.

It probably works because the ship speed is relatively low, so that the beam tracking can adjust the beam to the ship's position.

Can this technology be applied to an aircraft (e.g. speed, antenna size) ?

My first guess would that the

- aircraft speed is too high, so the beam tracking system may not be able to adapt in real-time (beam is 700 km wide)
- the antenna size is too big (1.2m diameter) to be integrated in the aircraft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly will not work.  I'm not sure about the tracking speed issue, but then antenna gain from a parabolic antenna mounted on a ship (or fixed site) is much greater than that of any sort of aircraft mounted flat panel array.
Unless the provider was willing (and able) to turn up the power on the spotbeam your aircraft is operating in, your downlink snr (signal to noise ratio) will be too low to use.

Comment: Does a low SNR make it impossible to transmit data ? As far as I remember, if the SNR is low, a good error correction protocol must be used, so the bandwidth will be low. But you may still be able to get a network connection.